# iOS app: Some parts of code snippets are replaced with UUIDs in the edit revision view

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, ios-app, revisions-list

When I checked my suggested edit of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/178181/21444) on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), I thought I must have messed it up, by accidentally pasting something into a code block / code snippet.

Actually *I didn't change the code in the question at all*, so I think that something must be broken in the revision view on the iOS app.

---

The preview of the revision looked like this:
[image: Revision view in mobile app]
Here's the [full screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm9pj.jpg).

---

Even *after* the edit was *approved* only these UUIDs are shown, instead of the actual source code:

[image: Revision view in mobile app]

---

When I double checked it on my computer, it showed everything as expected:

[image: Revision view on desktop computer]

---

Is this a bug? Or is this by design? Is this related to code snippets or code in general? Can this be fixed?

---

<sup>I'm running the latest version (1.6.6.2) of the Stack Exchange app.</sup>

Comment: after submitting the edit, are you able to run the snippet? I noticed this few times

Comment: After the edit was approved, the snippet worked as expected. Unfortunately I didn't run the snippet, while the edit was pending, @OptimusPrime.